# Suggestions for a small ground rover that runs ROS?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I understand that this question might be somewhat out of scope here. But I hope that answers.ros.org is better than the mailing list. Please feel free to correct me otherwise.

Can you recommend a small ground rover which:

- has max dimension of within 1 foot (somewhere between small toy rovers and a Clearpath Husky)
- fairly light and easy to lift by hand (<6 kg)
- fairly cheap either to buy or to build (maybe around USD 600)
- is capable of navigating in fairly rough terrain (like rocks or swamp)
- has a well-known slip model for its wheels
- can either receive command velocities over a wireless link remotely or can physically support a netbook running ROS

I can't think of anything to tag this question with :-(

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36367/suggestions-for-a--small-ground-rover-that-runs-ros?/) by [PKG](https://answers.ros.org/users/671/pkg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 365 on 2012-06-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the lightweight UGV system we built for RoboCup Rescue fits quite nicely to your list of requirements (not perfectly, but pretty close). It's based on the ["Wild Thumper" robot kit chassis](http://robosavvy.com/store/product_info.php/cPath/21_1200/products_id/2247). Two videos are available [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7zcr5IVYHN4) and [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PfPMvbfPHIg). If everything goes well, a upgraded version incorporating a LIDAR and 5 DOF arm will be used at RoboCup 2012 next week ;).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PKG](https://answers.ros.org/users/671/pkg/) on 2012-06-12**:
Could I know what controller you used and where you got the ROS drivers?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2012-06-12**:
It's using this Arduino based controller: http://www.sparkfun.com/products/11057 I did the communication myself, as rosserial didn't work with the resource-limited atmega168. The software is not in a public repository yet as it's not very polished, but I can change that, time permitting.

**Comment by [tommytwoeyes](https://answers.ros.org/users/1653/tommytwoeyes/) on 2015-12-21**:
@StefanKohlbrecher Stefan, I realize your post is quite old, but may I ask, do you have any documentation from your build of the UGV robot based on the Wild Thumper still? I am attempting to build a similar robot using the Wild Thumper, and I'm looking for any docs I can find. Thanks!